# vb.net removing contexts of first element in array

Tags: vb.net

how do i remove the contents of an array element such that if

```
hello(0) = "hello"
hello(1) = "hello123"
hello(2) = "hello123123"
```

i want the result to be

```
hello(0)="hello123"
hello(1) = "hello123123"
```

Comment: How does your existing data exactly look? Are you following some pattern NOW or do you want to incorporate a fresh pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
hello = hello.Skip(1).ToArray
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new array that's one element smaller than your source array, and copy the contents of the source array (excluding the first element) into the new array.